# How to output the time between each press of the spacebar with pynput in python

Tags: python, pynput

I am trying to get the time in between each press of the spacebar and output it to a text file, so that it will show a runnable log of each delay. I test it, and it runs, however nothing appears in the text file. Here is my code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from playsound import playsound
import time

def on_press(key):
    global key2
    key2 = key

with Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

while True:
    done = False
    if key2 == "'s'":
        file = open("script.txt", "r")
        exec(file.read())
        file.close()
        playsound("beep.mp3")
        while done == False:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            timer += 0.01
            if key2 == "key.space":
                str = str + "\ntime.sleep(" + timer + ")"
                timer = 0
            if key2 == "'a'":
                str = str + "\ntime.sleep(" + timer + ")"
                timer = 0
                file = open("script.txt", "a")
                file.write(str)
                file.close()
                done = True
            if key2 == "'d'":
                timer = 0
                str = ""
                done = True
```

Please note that I am OK at coding, but not super good. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: This answer is solely for helping out with the "nothing appears in the text file" part.

> ```
> file = open("script.txt", "r")
> file.close()
> ```

According to this,

1. You are opening the file in reading mode so you can't write to it
2. You are closing the file as soon as you open it. There is no interaction and these two lines of code seem trivial to me.

If you do not know how to read/ write from a file using python, I suggest you learn about that first (there are many online resources and explanations for this).

Additionally, I would suggest debugging your code using an editor capable of doing it visually (like PyCharm) to better understand the point at which your code does not behave the way you want it to.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't make this clear. That part was just to run the code. I was going to use exec() on the text file, which I have edited in now. The place where I write is a bit farther into the code. Also, I did run this in pycharm: however I couldn't find the solution to the problem. Thanks for responding so quickly. I thought I was gonna have to wait a while.

Comment: Ah, I see. So what is the problem here to be exact? Is it that absolutely nothing is being written to the text file, or is it that the time is not being recorded properly?

Comment: The problem is that the text file has absolutely nothing. If you run my newly edited code, the output is exactly the same. I don't mean to be annoying, but you should read the code more carefully. If you look, the place where there is text output is at the part that says `if key2 == "'a'":
                str = str + "\ntime.sleep(" + timer + ")"
                timer = 0
                file = open("script.txt", "a")
                file.write(str)
                file.close()`

Comment: The reason I have the read file is so that I can run the code I am generating, and then add on some more. I am planning to record the space bar and output it as mouse output in selenium.

Comment: OH, now I see what you are trying to do

Comment: try starting you listener like `listener = Listener (on_press=on_press)  \n  listener.start()`

Answer (score 0):

One simply way that occurs to me is using `time.time()`

```
import time
start = time.time()
diff = time.time() - start # Difference between starting time and current time
```

Which could led to

```
...
while True:
  start = time.time()
  ...
    if key2 == "key.space":
      diff = time.time() - start
```